# Artemesia - Silver Mound (Wormwood) - soil and watering

Tags: watering, potting-soil

My Artemesia - most likely a Silver Mound (Wormwood) has its leaves drooping, with some of the lower leaves turning yellow and tips browning. The plant is only about 6" tall, and staying outdoors in zone 7, in a 12" diameter pot and part-sun. The pot has regular potting soil with a lot of perlite. I recently replanted it with perlite to try and get the yellowing to stop, but it does not seem to be helping after 2 days. I did water it a little right after replanting just to get the soil around the roots to settle. I can feel moisture in the soil two digits in. Maybe I did not water it enough? The leaves are droopy like hair.

Does it need less water or more? Should I replant it in a more well-draining soil, like ones made for cactuses? Thanks in advance.

*** Update: 8/1/2022: I noticed a few of the leaves were shriveling and felt dry to the touch. Not yellowing or tips browning, but shriveling evenly throughout the leaf. So I went with watering more. I watered the pot thoroughly. After 1 day, the droopy leaves all perked up. Not back to 100% to the way it was when I bought it at the nursery, but still perked up nonetheless. After the second day, they perked up a bit more. So, generally it's headed in the right direction.

Comment: Can your add a picture of your plant ?

Comment: Actually, it all sounds correct, and it "is largely immune to most pests and diseases." according to https://www.thespruce.com/silver-mound-artemisia-low-perennial-groundcover-2132049

Answer (score 2):

Drooping could be from too much water or not enough water, or an indication of something else that is wrong. Likely, if you watered it, wait and see if it'll perk up and if not give it a day or two and replant in more well draining soil, maybe a soil combination of desert with potting soil, as Artemisia does well naturally in deserts.